# Is there a way to get a list of all opened files for a process using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Our application is cross-platform and thus written in Qt. The target platforms are Windows and Mac. In our project we need to determine a list of all opened files for a separate process. For now we do it in a platform dependent way using WinAPI and corresponding Mac OsX APIs. This approach has already caused many problems as long as we need to maintain two unrelated versions of the program.

If it can be any helpful, we need to determine a list of opened audio files for such programs as Traktor and Serato (Dj Intro and Scratch Live). And the version of Qt we are using is 4.8.0.

So, the question will be, is there any platform-independent way to get a list of opened files? Or maybe at least a some kind of workaround using some third party libraries or utils?

Comment: Generally - no (even for QT). But you might find a way for your specific case (just for this specific programs).

Comment: @fork0 Unfortunately, there are no public APIs available for any of those programs (and any other Dj software AFAIK). We have investigated that opportunity in the first turn.

Answer (score 1):

Even Qt is not platform independant ;) It just encapsulates the platform specifics (like WIN32 API vs. X11 API) under a common API. I would to the same in your case: design a (Qt based) class which provides the API you need in your application, and then use your already existing (platform specific) code to provide the functionality you need. In your Application, you would only use the Qt based API, and you do not need to worry about platform specifics in your application code. Also, you can write any number of unit tests against your API to make sure it behaves correctly.

Example (not 100% complete code!):

In your header file:

```
class QMySpecificAPI : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT    // only required when you need signals/slots

public:
    QList<QString> getOpenFiles();
}
```

In your cpp file:

```
#include "QMySpecificAPI.h"

#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
QList<QString> QMySpecificAPI::getOpenFiles() {
   // Use WIN32 API to retrieve the file list
}
#endif

#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
QList<QString> QMySpecificAPI::getOpenFiles() {
    // Use MACOSX API to retrieve the file list
}
#endif
```

Especially since you say that you already have a lot of issues with your existing code, I strongly suggest to implement unit test cases and have them run regularly to automatically check your code, like

```
...
QMySpecificAPI api;
QList<QString> fileList = api.getOpenFiles();
ASSERT(fileList.count() == 5);   // or whatever you expect
...
```

Comment: Yes, we've already done exactly that thingy, at least without unit tests (: The problem remains the same - I was hoping there is a way which I can use to be sure that my code will work on all platforms. I have only windows dev machine and can't test my changes instantly on a mac one. If I used Qt APIs it would be a sort of garanty for me.