# How to determine an order of opening files for a process?

Tags: c++, winapi, internal, ntdll

Is there a way to get all opened file handles for a process and arrange it by time files were opened? We have a project, which requires exactly this - we need to determine which files are opened by a Dj software, such as Traktor or Serato. The reason we need to know its order is to determine, which file is in the first deck, and which is in the second one.

Currently we are using Windows internal APIs from the Ntdll.dll (Winternl.h) to determine a list of all opened files for a process. Maybe that's not the best way to do it. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

We relied on an observed behavior of that APIs on certain OS version and certain Dj software versions, which was that the list of all opened files for a process never get rearranges, i.e. adheres an order. I know that's a bad practice, but it was a "should be" feature from the customer right before the release, so we had to. The problem is now we have a bug when those handles are sometimes randomly rearranged without any particular cause. That brakes everything. I thought maybe there would be a field in those win structures to obtain file's been opened time, but seemingly there are no such things. Docs on that APIs are quite bad.

I thought about some code paste, but it's a function 200 lines long and it uses indirect calls from the dll using function pointers and all structures for WinAPIs are redefined manually, so it's really hard to read it. Actually, the Winternl.h header isn't even included - all stuff is loaded manually too, like that:

```
GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation" );
```

It's really a headache for a cross platform application...

**P.S.** I have posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475132/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-opened-files-for-a-process-using-qt) about any cross-platform or Qt way to get opened file handles, maybe that stuff will be useful or related.

Comment: This looks very much like an XY question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

if it's just to check the behavior in other OS  for debug purpose, you can use the technique of creating process in debug mode and intercept in the order all events of dll loading, here's a good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger) talking about that.